# How to init libs in unit tests with mockito

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mocking, mockito

I have a problem that when I do tests, the library that requires init gives an error that it has not been called, how can I init it in the test or mock it so that there is no error? For example now i have a problem with Paper.book

In my Application class in onCreate I have init of Paper

```
Paper.init(applicationContext)
```

and when test tried to do that

```
 Paper.book().write(Constants.NAMES_KEY, Names(firstName, middleName, lastName))
```

I have an error that init is not called

```
io.paperdb.PaperDbException: Paper.init is not called
```

I can uderstend why, but how i can fix it? Where i can init it or mock in test?

Comment: Hi! Have you find a solution?

Comment: @Grecha hi, no, I removed Paper)

Comment: hehe I did the same with my issue